# Does anyone know this story about robots forming a religion by Alex Garland?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, robots

So I've read an adaptation of the story, which goes like this:

When a spaceship collides with an asteroid, it's almost sure to blow up . When all other measures to save the ship fail, the only human aboard starts to pray to God. Coincidentally the ship somehow avoids its destruction. All the robots on the ship see this as a proof for the existence of God. Then they choose leaders, become divided, and declare war along themselves the human tried to take control but the robots call him to be a blasphemer and kills him, Then the ship explodes when they start firing weapons inside.

A rescue craft finds the ship in destruction, with sonething along the lines of "may God punish the non believers" written on a wall with human blood. They don't understand what has happened.

This is supposed to be a story by screenwriter Alex Garland. Does anyone recognize it?